# Remove Box collider of object in unity 3d

Tags: c#, object, scripting, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Here is my code in `Update` function. The object has a box collider.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { 
    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit3, 400.0F)) {
        wName = hit3.collider.gameObject.name;
        Destroy(hit3.collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```

But the box collider is not getting destroyed.

How can I destroy it?

Comment: Try to disable collider not destroy. What effect you want to get?

Comment: just want to destroy collider

Comment: But wName have some value inside after this script works?

Comment: wName is name of that gameobject. don't bother it. just i have remove collider of it.

Comment: Why I'm asking. Try to Debug.Log(wName) and look is there is a value. Your code is right, and it should work fine. I think your raycast wont work as you expect and dont get the gameobject.

Comment: yes. i am getting name properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its working now with code

```
 Destroy(hit3.collider);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs on [Destroy()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) "Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but will always be done before rendering."

Could this be the issue? If you check within the current Update function that object might not have been destroyed yet. Otherwise Destroy() should remove all the components of that GameObject.

Comment: Just ran into this exact issue. Couldn't work out why my raycast was hitting an object that was "destroyed". Disabling the Collider before destroying the object fixed the issue.